# Convergence of two series with a parameter $\alpha > 0$ and $x>1$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I have to study the convergence of these two series with $\alpha > 0$ and $x > 1$

$$\sum_{n = 2}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(\log n!)^{\alpha}}$$

and

$$\sum_{n = 2}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(\log x)^{\log n}}$$

For the first one, using the Gamma function, I found that

\begin{align}\sum_{n = 2}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(\log n!)^{\alpha}} &\le \sum_{n = 2}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^{\alpha}(\log n)^{\alpha}}\\&\le \sum_{n = 2}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^{\alpha}n^{\alpha /2}} \\&= \sum_{n = 2}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^{3\alpha/2}}\end{align} which converges $\forall\alpha > 2/3$. Am I right?

For the second series I can't find out a solution, any hint will be appreciated. Thank you

Comment: "which converges $\forall\alpha>0$." Check again with your p-series. And note that $\sum\frac1{(n\log n)^\alpha}$ converges sometimes when $\sum\frac1{n^{3\alpha/2}}$ diverges.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the series $\sum_{n = 2}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(\log n!)^{\alpha}}$, note that $\log(n!)=\sum_{k=2}^n \log(k)$ and $\int_{k-1}^{k}\ln(t) dt\leq \log(k)\leq \int_{k}^{k+1}\ln(t) dt$

You should then be able to prove that $\log(n!)\sim n\log(n)$.

Therefore $\sum_{n = 2}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(\log n!)^{\alpha}}$ follows the same convergence as $\sum_{n = 2}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(n\log(n))^{\alpha}}$ which converges if and only if $\alpha >1$.

---

For the series $\sum_{n = 2}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(\log x)^{\log n}}$, note that $(\log x)^{\log n}=n^{\log\log x}$, hence the series converges iff $\log(\log(x))>1\iff x>e^e$.

Comment: I think that more precisely the first series converges $\forall \alpha > \frac{2}{3}$. Do you agree?

Comment: @brt22 I disagree, it diverges whenever $\alpha \leq 1$.

Comment: My mistake, the second estimation in my calculations is wrong, in fact $logt \le \sqrt{t} \Rightarrow \frac{1}{logt} \ge \frac{1}{\sqrt{t}}$

Comment: So is it correct if I write $$\sum_{n = 2}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(\log n!)^{\alpha}} \le \sum_{n = 2}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^{\alpha}(\log n)^{\alpha}} \le \sum_{n = 2}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^{\alpha}} < \infty \Leftrightarrow \alpha > 1$$ ?

Comment: @brt22 I agree with the inequalities. I disagree with what you derived. All you proved is $\alpha > 1 \implies \sum_{n = 2}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(\log n!)^{\alpha}} <\infty$. If you want more, consider [the limit comparison test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_comparison_test)

Comment: I  tried with the limit comparison test, but the limit is 0 both if I take $a_n = \frac{1}{n^{\alpha}}$ or $a_n = \frac{1}{logn^{\alpha}}$

Comment: With which sequences do you use the limit comparison test?

Comment: Since $\log(n!)\sim n\log(n)$, $\lim_n \frac{\log(n!)}{n\log(n)}=1$, hence $\lim_n \left(  \frac{\log(n!)}{n\log(n)}\right)^{\alpha}=1$ and you can apply the limit comparison test to $(\log(n!))^{\alpha}$ and $(n\log(n))^{\alpha}$

Answer (score 0):

For the second series:
$$\lim_{n\to \infty} n\log (\frac{a_n}{a_{n+1}})=\lim_{n\to \infty} n \log(1+\frac{1}{n})\log\log x\\=\log\log x$$
So by Logarithmic test series will converge for $$\log\log x>1$$ i.e for $$x>e^e$$

Comment: Is it possible to solve it with another test?

Comment: Yeah, now I found Cauchy's condensation test https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_condensation_test  easier than Logarithmic test